# raspberry-pi3 screen is not coming?

Tags: ssh, putty, raspberry-pi3, hdmi

I have bought a new raspberry-pi3 model.As per my knowledge, I have made all the connection right, and both the red and green light is turn on.

```
In the router,I saw the ip-address of my device with IP-address as-"192.168.0.106"   
with name "recovery". I also ping the device and it is successfully reachable across networks.
```

I tried to login through putty but got some network unreachable error, while login with putty, I given my raspberrypi ip address as host on ssh port 22. through nmap command i got to know that all 1000 ports for this device "raspbeerypi" is closed.

I don't know why the raspberry screen is not showing in windows-10 and even in ubuntu-14.04 lts, which is running in Vmware workstation. the disc image folder is also not showing in file directory. i connected the HDMI cable correctly.
steps which i followed:-
    1. sd card with  noobs preinstalled, has inserted.
    2. ethernet cable is plugged into modem and raspberry-pi.
    3. HDMI cable connected to laptop monitor and raspberry-pi.
    4. power on the raspberry-pi.

Comment: what do you by not showing in windows 10 ? All you need to do is write the image to your RPi using diskimager and plug SD card in RPi. Connect it to HDMI then.
What steps did you follow ?

Comment: @Sufiyan, I got the disk image preinstalled with noobs remaining followed all the steps correctly but nothing comes to screen.

Comment: i just edited the question with steps.

Comment: which laptop monitor do you have ? does it support HDMI input ?

Comment: what _is_ on the screen? nothing at all? Does anything happen at all? You could try SSH-ing in to verify it's running. Make certain your power supply supplies enough current, or it will just keep resetting. This is the mistake I made

Comment: dell-Inspiron, and HDMI port is already given then  i hope this will support HDMI also.

Answer (score 2):

Your laptop HDMI port is an output port, not an input port. You cannot use it as an input.
You have to `ssh` into your Raspberry pi and then setup VNC server to access GUI.
Follow these steps,

- Check the ip address of your Raspberry pi from your router.
- SSH into your RPi using puTTy if you are using windows, or type `ssh
  pi@ipAddress` if you are using Linux.
- Enter default username `pi` and password `raspberry`
- Once you are logged in run the following commands, `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install tightvncserver` , in that order.
- Once it is installed run `vncserver :1` to start vnc server.

Please visit here for more details,
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-lesson-7-remote-control-with-vnc/installing-vnc

Comment: ha well spotted

Comment: can u plz tell me the steps also how to do ssh. if i am not wrong this is something like ssh user@ip-address through ubuntu. as i am able to ping my raspberry through ping.

Comment: i tried to access through putty but it is giving me message it is unreachable and fatal error. i enter user as my ip-address and using ftp port 22.

Comment: how can `user` be an ip address ? you need to find the ip address of your raspberry or if the hostname is default then try `raspberrypi` instead of ip address.

Comment: once the connection is established only then i can use username "pi" and password "raspberry".

Comment: in putty i given user as my raspberry - pi ip- address

Comment: you need to learn to ssh using putty. Please google `how to ssh into raspberry pi` for more details and come back here.

Comment: Just a note: **SOME** laptops have HDMI **input** ports specifically for display purposes. See some recent (~3 year) Alienware gaming laptops for an example.

Comment: unable to login through putty to my raspberry-pi device using its IP address, got some network unreachable error. nmap command shows me that all 1000 ports for this device is closed. what should i do??